# Umbraco 8 - How to get invariant properties values in case of publishing only the secondary culture node?

Tags: umbraco8

I have an application which has two variant languages (English - Arabic) . When I publish node in Arabic only without English. All invariant properties are null and not even exists external index.

To create the The issue :

1. In back-office, create a node which have title (text box vary by culture) , date(datepicker do not vary by culture) ,& Image (ImageCropper do not vary by culture).
2. Save and publish in Arabic culture only.
3. Try to look at externl index for the created node,  text has value while image  and date do not.
4. view ContentModel object is also has empty properties

Is there a way to get these(date, image) values without publishing these properties in English Node ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a bug :-( If you haven't already, try asking over on our.umbraco.com or create and issue on github.com/umbraco/umbraco-cms/issues (after you've made sure that the issue hasn't already been reported, of course).

Comment: Thanks  @JannikAnker :) . I found this issue in thier github and it is closed because it is out of their scope :( .

Answer (score 1):

I found this github issue#5532 states the issue , it is closed with no solution. It is out of their scope.  Here is the contributor ronaldbarend commented on Oct 6, 2020

---

*"This can't be fixed without completely rewriting the way element types are stored, as currently all data is stored as JSON in a single property. There's a RFC to change this, but the feature to keep variants in sync is explicitly stated as being out of scope: umbraco/rfcs#24."

---

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/5532